# Using newer boost library with a precompiled binary using an older version

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have a precompiled binary that used boost version 1.58.0. My currently installed boost library is version 1.65.1. When trying to execute the binary on Ubuntu 18.04, the following error occurs:

```
$ ./binary_file
$ ./binary_file: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I make it work with my version or, if it's not possible, install the older boost version and run it without conflicts?

Comment: You either have to downgrade the boost you are building with or upgrade the boost that is on your target system.

Comment: might be of use: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24811/changing-linked-library-for-a-given-executable-centos-6